# adding design packages (bpls) in delphi IDE (automatically)

Tags: delphi, ide

I am trying to automate Delphi Environment regeneration we have bunch of bpl-s that has to be installed in a fresh delphi.

I need to automate this somehow from Delphi 5 it would be : Components->Install Packages->Add...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/multiinstaller/index.htm

Comment: http://rvelthuis.de/programs/compinstall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of installed IDE packages is stored in registry, so you could update it there.

The actual location depends on Delphi version, on my machine for D7 it's:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Known Packages`

and for D2007 it's

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\4.0\Known Packages`

Comment: DOn't forget to adjust the lirary path also; the dcu's and pas files need to be found also or else you will get errors while compiling.