# delphi package automation installer into ide

Tags: delphi, ide, automation

Found a tool here long ago, and never had the time to test it.

does anyone have a link to a tool that with it , you can automate the installation of packages into Delphi IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this : [Delphi Package Installer](http://code.google.com/p/delphipi/) on the web recently. Haven't tested it yet, but you might try it.
Cheers.

Comment: tried it, and most of the components work out of the box. nice.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add your component's bpl to Delphi "Known Packages" registry key, details :

[adding design packages (bpls) in delphi IDE (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299031/adding-design-packages-bpls-in-delphi-ide-automatically)

Answer (score 2):

You can download the JVCL from [Project JEDI](http://delphi-jedi.org), and look at it's installer. Regardless of your needs (installing pre-compiled component packages or compiling and installing version specific packages), you can do it with the source from the JEDI installer. It comes with full source, a very comprehensive demo (the JVCL or JCL installation itself), and is free.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of [Silverpoint Development's MultiInstaller](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/multiinstaller/index.htm).  I believe it's used by several common component packages.

Comment: Why the -1?  As far as I can tell from the original question, this tool does exactly what's asked for.

Comment: i didn't the -1 however, after trying the multiInstaller, it failed in flaming colors.

Comment: How so? If you post details here or the Embarcadero forums, someone could help you.